# Lua: How does Tir compare to Luvit?

Tags: lua, web-deployment

For web development in **Lua**, how does **[Tir](http://tir.mongrel2.org/)** differ from **[Luvit](http://luvit.io/)** ?

They both appear to support asynchronous I/O.

Does one framework have limitation or requirements the other one doesn't (e.g. does Tir require the use of Mongrel2?)

Comment: Where did you read that Tir supports asyncronous I/O? I can't find anything about that.

Comment: I thought it did. If it doesn't, that'd be a good answer and indicate that's a difference